# WPF Expander - Button in Header

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building an expander control where I want to have an additional button in the header (additional to the toggle). When I add a button on the `<Expander.Header>`, the binded command is not triggered when it is clicked.

I have tried creating a style/template for the Expander and Expander.Header so that the Expander's toggle is only triggered on its click (rather than the entire header). I did this thinking that it is some sort of heirarchical issue where the header is consuming the click event rather than my button, but it did not work out as I had hoped...

Is there a specific way I should modify the template to allow for a button to be placed in the header and have the button's command executed?

xaml of my expander control - all bound to my VM, can confirm the binding works correctly:

```
<Expander Background="White">
    <Expander.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="center"
                FontSize="16"
                Margin="5 0 5 0"
                Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Button
                Grid.Column="2"
                Width="15"
                Height="15"
                Margin="10 10 10 10"
                Command="{Binding OpenButtonCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Expander.Header>

    <TextBlock Margin="30 0 0 0">This is a test sub component</TextBlock>

</Expander>
```

Thank you

Comment: There is no error in this XAML. It is fully operational.

Comment: There may be an error in the implementation of the ViewModel or in the assignment of the ViewModel instance to the data context.

Comment: I have tested, it is actually working. Are you missing a public command binding?

Comment: Where and how is `OpenButtonCommand` implemented and what's the `DataContext` of the `Expander`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it should be working;

Tested with following VM:

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public DelegateCommand OpenButtonCommand { get; private set; }

        private string m_Name = "Test Name";

        public string Name
        {
            get { return m_Name; }
            set
            {
                m_Name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            OpenButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenButtonCommandExecute);
        }

        private void OpenButtonCommandExecute()
        {
            Name = "clicked";
        }
    }
}
```

and XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Expander
        Width="300"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Background="White">
        <Expander.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="5,0,5,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="16"
                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                    TextAlignment="Left"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Width="15"
                    Height="15"
                    Margin="10,10,10,10"
                    Command="{Binding OpenButtonCommand}" />
            </Grid>
        </Expander.Header>

        <TextBlock Margin="30,0,0,0">This is a test sub component</TextBlock>

    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i think the OP's problem is, by click the button, he doesn't want `Name = "clicked";`, instead, he wants the **expander to be expanded**, which is why he defined a custom header.

Comment: @LeiYang he says _"the binded command is not triggered when it is clicked... , Is there a specific way I should modify the template to allow for a button to be placed in the header and have the button's command executed?"_ But it is triggered.

Comment: 'Header so that the Expander's toggle is only triggered on its click (rather than the entire header)' --- that's the goal. and the button's command is only for debugging purpose.

Comment: Yeah I understand you, at that moment where click command triggered, in your view model you can also set the state of expander. It is expanded or not expanded.

Comment: but the logic seems a bit strange. is there any way to let button expand the header without code behind/events?

Comment: But you think it is logical to put a button to header and except to be working a expander toggle ? Button is doing its job. If you want to do an operation on expansion, you should be listening `IsExpanded` property.